# Implementing the D3 "reusable chart" pattern in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

The code in **section 2** below (working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/mjmitche/tzboups3/2/)) is based on the code in section 1 but changed to use arrow functions, and it is based on Mike Bostock's pattern in [Toward Resusable Charts](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/chart/), namely returning a function that has other functions on it.

If I try to run either the code in section 1 or 2 in typescript  (demo [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20mychart%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20stop%20%3D%20false%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20let%20chart%20%3D%20function%20(selection)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20function%20tick()%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20tick%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chart.addToChart%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20chart%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20chart.stop%20%3D%20function%20()%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20stop%20%3D%20true%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20chart%3B%0D%0A%7D%3B%20%0D%0A))  it says the methods `addToChart` and `stop` do not exist on type `(selection: any) => () => void`.

#### How can I get typescript to recognize the functions properties (`addToChart` and `stop` in this case) added to the returned function?

**section 1**

```
const mychart = function (){
  let stop = false;
  const chart = function(selection){
    function tick(){
      console.log("tick");
    }
    return tick;
  };

  // Adding a function to the returned 
  // function as in Bostock's reusable chart pattern
  chart.addToChart = function(value){ 
    console.log("addToChart");
    return chart;
  };

  chart.stop = function(){
    return stop = true;
  }

  return chart;
}

const a = mychart();
const tick = a();
tick(); //logs tick
a.addToChart(); //logs "addToChart"
```

**section 2**

```
const mychart = () => {
  let stop = false;

  const chart = (selection) => {
    function tick(){
      console.log("tick");
    }
    return tick;
  };

  chart.addToChart = (value) => {
    console.log("addToChart");
    return chart;
  };

  chart.stop = () => {
    return stop = true;
  }

  return chart;
} 

const a = mychart();
const tick = a();
tick(); //logs tick
a.addToChart(); //logs "addToChart"
```

Comment: For anyone arriving from my tweet about the bounty, I'm pretty sure the normal function vs. arrow function distinction made in the question is a bit of a red herring; TypeScript has difficulties with this style of code regardless of lexical scope. The bigger question is how you annotate the "closures with getters and setters" style of code in TS.

Answer (score 7):

You can define a [hybrid type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#hybrid-types), i.e. an interface describing both the function's signature as well as its properties. Given your code it could be something like this:

```
interface IChart {
    (selection: any): any;
    // Use overloading for D3 getter/setter pattern
    addToChart(): string;               // Getter
    addToChart(value: string): IChart;  // Setter
}
```

Since you should avoid `any` like the plague this might need some further refinement, but it should be enough to get you started. Furthermore, to allow for a *D3-ish* getter/setter pattern you can [overload](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#overloads) the `addToChart` function in the interface declaration.

Integrating this interface as a type in your reusable code pattern now becomes pretty straightforward:

```
const mychart = (): IChart => {

  // Private value exposed via closure
  let value: string|undefined;

  const chart = <IChart>((selection) => {
    // Private logic
  });

  // Public interface
  // Implementing a  D3-style getter/setter.
  chart.addToChart = function(val?: string): any {
    return arguments.length ? (value = val, chart) : value;
  };

  return chart;
} 

const chart = mychart();

console.log(chart.addToChart())   // --> undefined       
chart.addToChart("Add");          // Sets private value to "Add".
console.log(chart.addToChart())   // --> "Add"
```

Have a look at the executable [playground demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20IChart%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20(selection%3A%20any)%3A%20any%3B%0D%0A%20%20addToChart()%3A%20string%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Getter%0D%0A%20%20addToChart(value%3A%20string)%3A%20IChart%3B%20%20%2F%2F%20Setter%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20mychart%20%3D%20()%3A%20IChart%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Private%20value%20exposed%20via%20closure%0D%0A%20%20let%20value%3A%20string%7Cundefined%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20const%20chart%20%3D%20%3CIChart%3E((selection)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Private%20logic%0D%0A%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Public%20interface%0D%0A%20%20%2F%2F%20Implementing%20a%20%20D3-style%20getter%2Fsetter.%0D%0A%20%20chart.addToChart%20%3D%20function(val%3F%3A%20string)%3A%20any%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20arguments.length%20%3F%20(value%20%3D%20val%2C%20chart)%20%3A%20value%3B%0D%0A%20%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20return%20chart%3B%0D%0A%7D%20%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20chart%20%3D%20mychart()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconsole.log(chart.addToChart())%20%20%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20undefined%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0D%0Achart.addToChart(%22Add%22)%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Sets%20private%20value%20to%20%22Add%22.%0D%0Aconsole.log(chart.addToChart())%20%20%20%2F%2F%20--%3E%20%22Add%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20).

Comment: This is excellent, and probably the closest I've seen to this working. However, overloading the interface causes everything to break — try adding the following to the interface, which would be the getter version of addToChart: `addToChart(): string;`

Comment: If you combine the two addToChart methods into something like `yScale(scale?: any): this | string;` it works, but that seems to distort the meaning of the declaration — if `scale` is defined, the return will be `this`; if it's not defined, the return will be `string`. There's no instance in which supplying no arguments will result in it returning `this`.

Comment: You beat me to it. I just included exactly that in my answer... But, as you have already mentioned, I am not completely happy with that.

Comment: @aendrew Have a look at the edit, which introduces overloading of the `addToChart` function for clarity.

Comment: I was seriously scratching my head for ten minutes while trying to replicate this, which is imminently sensible — worth noting `const chart = <IChart>((selection) => {});` IS NOT EQUAL TO `const chart = <IChart>(selection) => {};`!

At any rate, this is a good answer and really helped me figure out what was happening with this all. I'll reward the bounty first chance I'm able to.

Comment: After a bit more testing, this is really close but I have one small issue with it — if you initialise a variable in the parent scope (i.e., alongside `let stop = false`) and then use the overloaded getter/setter pattern, I get a "not assignable to type" error. Any idea how to set initial values in the parent scope using this pattern?

Comment: @aendrew I am afraid, I don't get what you are after. Isn't `value` used in exactly that way? Declared in parent scope and used in getter/setter afterwards. If you are looking for something else, please be more specific or set up a demo.

Comment: Apologies if I wasn't clear; here's an online IDE where you can see the error being returned by TS. N.b., I don't think `chart.addToChart` is working as you're expecting it to, the `value` variable in the parent context I'm pretty sure isn't directly attached to the `this` context of the returned function (though I may be wrong; my linter was saying it was unused). https://codesandbox.io/s/jl8qvlzlky

Comment: @aendrew You are right, there were still some glitches in the code and it felt somewhat clumsy. Therefore, I boiled it down to the essentials and corrected the wrong use of `this`. It now works as expected and the linter is also fine with it. Here is an updated fork of your demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/21jv7lv57n

Answer (score 3):

I was wondering if you could use interface / class :

```
interface IChart {
    constructor: Function;
    addToChart?: (number) => Chart;
    stop: () => boolean;
}

class Chart implements IChart {

    private _stop = false;
    constructor( selection ) {
        // content of tick funciton here
    }

    public addToChart = function (n: number) {
        return this;
    }
    public stop = function () {
        return this._stop = true;
    }

}

let mychart = function () {
    let stop = false;
    let chartNew: Chart = new Chart(1);
    return chartNew;
};
```

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you. I gave you an upvote already and will accept once I test it in my code .

Comment: your playground example links to the example I posted in my OP.

Comment: sorry, it got a problem with buffer size, but you can copy and paste the code I posted as answer to the playground

Comment: I can't accept this answer because it changes the original code too much.  I'm looking to add a type to the original code, not change the original code to fit a type.

Comment: It's worth noting that very few people in the D3 community seem to use ES6 classes. Having to totally reimplement the pattern to use ES6 classes is not the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.assign` to create a hybrid type (a function that has extra properties), without having to define a dedicated interface. You can define the functions inside the original separately, so you can have multiple signatures for each function, and you can even type the `this` parameter if you want to access the object through `this` instead of `chart`

```
let mychart = function () {
    let isStopped = false;
    let value = "";


    type Chart = typeof chart;
    // Complex method with multiple signatures
    function addToChart(): string 
    function addToChart(newValue: string): Chart
    function addToChart(newValue?: string): string | Chart {
        if(newValue != undefined){
            value = newValue;
            chart.stop()
            return chart;
        }else{
            return value;
        }
    }
    // We can specify the type for this if we want to use this
    function stop(this: Chart) {
        isStopped = true;
        return this; // instead of chart, either is usable
    }
    var methods = {
        addToChart,
        stop,

        // inline function, we can return chart, but if we reference the Chart type explicitly the compiler explodes 
        stop2() {
            isStopped = true;
            return chart;
        }
    };
    let chart = Object.assign(function (selection) {
        function tick() {

        }
        return tick;
    }, methods);
    return chart;
}; 
let d = mychart();

d("");
d.addToChart("").addToChart();
d.addToChart();
d.stop();
d.stop().addToChart("").stop2().stop()
```

**Notes**

1. While intelisense work as expected, if you hover over `d` and look at the type, it is considerably uglier than a hand crafted version.
2. I defined `methods` separately and not inline on `Object.assign` because the compiler gets confused if I do.
3. If you don't want to use `this` inside the methods, you don't need to type `this` explicitly. I showed how to use it, just for the sake of completeness, using chart may be easier and it ensures that we don't have to deal with somebody passing in the wrong `this`.
4. While the example above works, there are certain cases in which the compiler gives up on inference and will type the return of `mychart` as any. One such case is when we reference `Chart` inside a function defined in the object assigned to `methods`

Comment: This isn't bad, but I feel @altocumulus' answer is a bit more idiomatic and succinct. This also doesn't really solve the problem of needing a union return type for an overloaded function.